# Google sheet script to create filter of pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have the following script to create simple pivot table. It is a working script. However, I am struggle to find sample codes to create a filter. Would appreciate if somebody can show me sample script to create a pivot table filter.

```js
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var pivotTableParams = {};


pivotTableParams.source = {
  sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()
};

pivotTableParams.rows = [{
  sourceColumnOffset: 8,
  "showTotals": true,
  sortOrder: "ASCENDING"
}];

pivotTableParams.values = [{
  summarizeFunction: "SUM",
  sourceColumnOffset: 10 
}];

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
ss.deleteSheet(sheet);  

var pivotTableSheet = ss.insertSheet('Sheet2');
var pivotTableSheetId = pivotTableSheet.getSheetId();

var request = {
  "updateCells": {
    "rows": {
      "values": [{
        "pivotTable": pivotTableParams
      }]
    },
    "start": {
      "sheetId": pivotTableSheetId
    },
    "fields": "pivotTable"
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that the question in the current form would be off topic for SO, since it basically just asks "show me the code".

Answer (score 1):

The documentation could use an example.

In the context of your code:

```
pivotTableParams.criteria = {
  8: {visibleValues: ["asdf", "fdsa"]},
  9: {visibleValues: ["sdaf", "fads"]},
  //and so on
};
```

Where the keys `8` and `9` above reference the columns in the pivot's source.  Similar to how `sourceColumnOffset` references them.

The `criteria` field is documented here: [Pivot Tables | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#PivotTable)

The `PivotFilterCriteria` type is documented here: [PivotFilterCriteria | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/PivotFilterCriteria)

From my investigation, I believe that `visibleValues` is the only key that you can pass and so can't filter by exclusion as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this thread trying to find an example of a working script with more detailed params being passed to the filter, here's a working example of a filter that removes all blank values and defaults all other values to being shown:

```
  // Filter blank cells  
  var condition = new Boolean();
  condition.type = "NOT_BLANK";
  pivotTableParams.criteria = { 0: {"condition": condition, "visibleByDefault": true}};
```

In this example, the "0" is the column index on the pivot table.

Here's the docs from the Google Sheets API, which are unfortunately short on examples so it can take a lot of trial and error to get things working:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#PivotFilterCriteria

Answer (score 0):

If somebody it´s trying to call the Sheets API in Apps Script, yo can add a filter to your pivot table objet with the following code

```
  var filter1 = Sheets.newPivotFilterCriteria()
  filter1.visibleValues = ['Sí']
  var spec1 = Sheets.newPivotFilterSpec()
  spec1.filterCriteria = filter1
  spec1.columnOffsetIndex = 0
  var filter2 = Sheets.newPivotFilterCriteria()
  filter2.visibleValues = dates
  var spec2 = Sheets.newPivotFilterSpec()
  spec2.filterCriteria = filter2
  spec2.columnOffsetIndex = 10
  var filter3 = Sheets.newPivotFilterCriteria()
  filter3.visibleValues = ['Negocio']
  var spec3 = Sheets.newPivotFilterSpec()
  spec3.filterCriteria = filter3
  spec3.columnOffsetIndex = 23
  pivotTable.filterSpecs = [spec1,spec2,spec3]
```